# reduce or delete existing root partition and install new distro

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation, automounting, mx-linux

I would like to delete my existing Mint root partition which is on `/dev/sda2` as its is very large space for root and I am out of space on the `/home` partition which is on `/dev/sda4`

I read online that reducing / resizing root will take time and there are risks while reducing/resizing by power failures which can corrupt the drive.

Hence my query is whether I can follow below steps:

1. Delete the existing root partition
2. create a new partition of 30 or 40 Gb
3. create another partition lets says partition X from what is left over after creating above new partition
4. run the MX linux installer and select the newly created 30/40Gb partition as `/` and keep the `/home` currently on the existing `/dev/sda4` partition intact. I would request some detailed help in doing so, basically a heads up in what option to select in the installer windows etc. just as a reassurance that I don`t mess up with` /home`...
5. finally any other steps to make sure newly created partition X is available for use when I boot in after installing MX.
6. In the [MX linux forums](https://forum.mxlinux.org/), someone suggested that:

   > allowing home to be within the Linux MX root, and use your existing /home (with a different mount point) as a data partition. 30 Gig is still big enough, but this way your personal MX configuration information will be integral to your MX installation and will not be confounded with the personal configuration files left over from Mint.

[`df` info here](https://pastebin.com/J8FsgBK6)

More info:

```
mike@mike-Vostro ~ $ inxi -F
System:    Host: mike-Vostro Kernel: 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.6  Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: Dell (portable) product: Vostro 15-3568
           Mobo: Dell model: 05HRPP v: A00
           Bios: Dell v: 01.08.00 date: 03/23/2017
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-6006U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 2000 MHz 1: 500 MHz 2: 500 MHz 3: 500 MHz
           4: 500 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-38-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Wireless 3165 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: 34:f6:4b:4c:22:be
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: 10:7d:1a:2c:84:5f
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (82.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM035 size: 1000.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 109G used: 8.3G (9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /home size: 800G used: 749G (99%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 8.88GB used: 0.21GB (2%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 229 Uptime: 2:02 Memory: 2364.3/3819.0MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: @Rui - thanks for the edits, looks better this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All steps sound reasonable.

**Before you start:**

Make a backup of your home partition or at least of all important files. You never know...

**Steps 1-3:**

I don't know the MX installer, but it might be easier to do the partitioning with a Linux Live CD and gparted. As you have an EFI boot partition this means your harddisk is very likely GPT partitioned and you boot from UEFI. This also means that more than 4 partitions (boot, system, extra, swap, home) should be no problem.

With gparted:

1. Delete `/dev/sda2`
2. Create one or two new partitions and format them (ext4?) and leave space to resize "home"
3. Resize your home partition `/dev/sda4`
4. Optional: Format the boot partition `/dev/sda1`

**Regarding Step 6:** You can now mount `/dev/sda4` and rename your user directory to not overwrite any existing configuration files with the new installation. You can move the files you want to keep after creating a new user account on the new system.

**Steps 4-5:**

As already said, I don't know the MX installer, but I guess you can choose "manual partitioning". As everything is set up and ready to use, you only need to choose the partitions and mount points for `/` (root), `swap`, `/opt` (or whatever mountpoint you want to use for your extra partition) and `/home` and make sure you don't check "format partition" anywhere.

If you're unsure what to select, make a photo and edit your question.

**Edit:**

Found a video on youtube: [Using MX Linux 17 installer, partitions,format,UEFI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5G-AQK_uIC4)

You should check `Preserve data in /home (if upgrading)`

Comment: thanks for all the inputs, will definitely work on this and get back in case of any issues/query.